# Disable Keynote Function Keys

Tags: itunes, keyboard, keynote

Keynote uses the <kbd>►ll</kbd>, <kbd>►►</kbd>, and <kbd>◄◄</kbd> keys to play/pause, go to previous slide, and next slide, respectively. This causes the keys to no longer control iTunes.

Is there any way to stop Keynote from handling these keys so that iTunes can respond to them? If I am working on a slideshow, I frequently use pause to stop music, which of course starts the slide show, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to disable control of Keynote, iPhoto, Aperture, or with these keys. These keys are bound to control whichever app is frontmost in the OS.